# CAPTCHA session reuse attack detected error message when form is submitted

Tags: webforms, captcha

I am experiencing problems with the captcha module 7.x-1.0-beta1 version. I have enabled captcha in webforms for anonymous users. After submitting the form it repeatedly gives me the error message,

> CAPTCHA session reuse attack detected

.. This happens for only one of the webform in which captcha is placed. I am using Drupal 7.2 version.

Any solution for this issue will be really helpful.

Comment: Have you tried disabling 'Cache page for anonymous users'?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because I have an ajax file upload on the form. The solution is to patch the captcha module with the patch found here http://drupal.org/node/918856#comment-6353912 .
You just need to download the patch and put it in the same folder and run in command line:

```
patch < captcha-patch-10022012.patch
```

if using git, you can just use :

```
git apply --directory=your/module/derectory captcha-patch-10022012.patch
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked for me, had to patch it using PHPstorm, since I'm on Windows (not by choice).  Netbeans will patch it, too... for any other Windows users out there!

Answer (score 0):

there is a Patch available for Drupal 7, please check this out: 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1395184